# CASE expression in WHERE clause with two values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to write a query to fetch data from table on the condition with the where clause is having case but I need to put or in the case statement but I am not able to find a solution:

Below is my query

```sql
SELECT WFET.InstanceID,
       WFI.SomeID
FROM [SOME_Instance] WFI
     INNER JOIN [SomeTracker] WFET ON WFI.InstanceID = WFET.InstanceID
     INNER JOIN SOMEPROP_INSTANCE WFPI ON WFET.ItemID = WFPI.WIID
WHERE WFI.InstanceID NOT IN (SELECT WFTT.InstanceID
                             FROM [SomeTracker] WFTT
                                  INNER JOIN [dbo].[SomeItems_Instance] WFII ON WFII.ITemID = WFTT.ItemID
                                  INNER JOIN SomeActivities WFA ON WFII.ActivityType = WFA.ActivityTypeID
                             WHERE WFTT.Status IN (CASE WHEN WFA.ActivityType <> 'Conn' THEN ('Running','Pending') ELSE 'Pending' END))
  AND WFI.Status = 'Running'
  AND WFPI.PropertyType <> 'Last'
GROUP BY WFET.InstanceID,
         WFI.SomeID;
```

Comment: Its a case **expression**, meaning it returns a single, atomic value. As such you cannot use it in this manner.

Comment: Please, also, don't SHOUT; we can read your inside words just fine.

Comment: ok but is there any way where I can organize my query where I can give two values

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read, and to write.

Comment: A `CASE` *expression* returns a scalar value. `THEN ('Running','Pending')` doesn't make sense as it's a list of values. The `THEN` can only return 1 value, not many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the `where` logic to:

```
WHERE WFTT.Status = 'Pending' OR
      (WFA.ActivityType <> 'Conn' AND WFIT.Status = 'Running')
```

Answer (score 1):

Rephrase the where clause in the subquery as:

```
WHERE
     (WFA.ActivityType <> 'Conn' AND WFTT.Status IN ('Running','Pending')) OR
      WFA.ActivityType = 'Conn' AND WFTT.Status = 'Pending'
```

Your use of `CASE` expressions was incorrect, because they must generate a single scalar value.  A `CASE` expression cannot generate a tuple, but we can still express the logic you want.

Full code:

```
WHERE WFI.InstanceID NOT IN (SELECT WFTT.InstanceID
                             FROM [SomeTracker] WFTT
                             INNER JOIN [dbo].[SomeItems_Instance] WFII
                                 ON WFII.ITemID = WFTT.ItemID
                             INNER JOIN SomeActivities WFA
                                 ON WFII.ActivityType = WFA.ActivityTypeID
                             WHERE
                                 WFA.ActivityType <> 'Conn' AND
                                 WFTT.Status IN ('Running','Pending') OR
                                 WFA.ActivityType = 'Conn' AND
                                 WFTT.Status = 'Pending')
```

Answer (score 0):

A `CASE` expression returns one value depending on boolean expressions. It cannot return a tuple. And we don't usually use `CASE` in the `WHERE` clause anyway, because the `WHERE` clause itself generates a boolean value. We use `AND`and `OR` instead to describe the desired restrictions.

Your expression

```
WHERE WFTT.Status IN (CASE WHEN WFA.ActivityType <> 'Conn'
                           THEN ('Running','Pending') ELSE 'Pending' END))
```

would be written as

```
WHERE WFTT.Status = 'Pending'
   OR (WFA.ActivityType <> 'Conn' AND WFTT.Status = 'Running')
```